# How to instrument categorical dummy variables

Tags: categorical-data, instrumental-variables

Suppose that X is a categorical variables for 4 possible regions.

Suppose that we want to evaluate the effect of X on an outcome Y, but we believe X is correlated with unobservables.

I separate X in four dummies, and specify my model as Y = b0 + b1*r1 (dummy for region 1) + b2*r2 + b3*r3 + controls + error term. (r4 omitted as reference point)

Can I instrument r1, r2, r3 with the same instrument as they are, in nature, the same categorical variable?  How can I instrument X in that scenario if I only have one good instrument for the variable X?

Comment: If you want to use an omitted category as a "reference point" you probably want an intercept in your model.

Comment: Yeah of course, there is one i just forgot to write it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more structure I don't think you can.

With just 2 regions my intuition of why IV works is that you can quasi-randomly move people from region 1 to region 2 or vice versa. This allows you to figure out the region effects.

With 3 regions you can use IV to quasi-randomly move people in and out of region 1. But where are you moving them? You will be moving some of them to region 2 and some of them to region 3. This will make it impossible to disentangle the effects of region 2 and region 3.

In a way, you will be able to figure out some kind of directional derivative, even though what you really are interested in is figuring out all partial derivatives.

To move onward you may want to put some assumptions on the generative process for the region dummies. This approach is promising if you believe that the endogeneity problem in all region dummies is caused by one underlying variable such as urbanization, availability of jobs.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you.